# How to understand constexpr function has "everything it needs" to compute its result at compile-time?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I come across [Demystifying constexpr](http://blog.quasardb.net/demystifying-constexpr/), and am a little confused about the examples in this post.

According to the post, `constexpr function` definition is like this:

> A constexpr function is able to compute its result at compilation
>   time, if its input is known at compilation time.
>
> In other words, any function that has "everything it needs" to compute
>   its result at compile-time, can be a constant expression.

For `add` function:

```
int add(int a, int b)  
{
    return a + b;
}
```

> Although the function is constexpr, you can use it with runtime value
>   just the same:

```
int main(int argc, char argv)  
{
    return add(argc, argc);
}
```

But for another function:

```
int add_vectors_size(const std::vector<int> & a, const std::vector<int> & b)  
{
  return a.size() + b.size()
}
```

The explanation of it can't be used as "`constexpr`" is:

> The compile time input are two vectors. Can we know at compile time
>   the size of a vector? The answer is no. Thus, add_vectors_size cannot
>   be a constant expression. We don't have "everything we need".

But per my understanding, for the first case, the `argc` value also can't be known during compile-time, and its value should be got at running time, correct? So how to understand `constexpr` function has "everything it needs" to compute
its result at compile-time?

Comment: Maybe you overlook the word "if" in "A constexpr function is able to compute its result at compilation time, **if** its input is known at compilation time."  `add(argc, argc)` is not known at compile-time;  `add(2, 3)` is

Comment: If this is actually the book explanation it's not very good: the reason `add_vectors_size` can't be `constexpr` is that there is no valid inputs. (A constexpr function must have at least 1 possible set of inputs which is known at compile-time)

Comment: @M.M Could you elaborate your explanation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is not really anything to elaborate

Comment: What is the meaning of "A constexpr function must have at least 1 possible set of inputs which is known at compile-time"? Honestly, I can't clearly get its meaning. Thanks!

Comment: @NanXiao: It means exactly what it says. If the function is declared in such a way that it is impossible to provide compile-time values to a function, then the function may not be declared `constexpr`. Like for example, declaring it with parameters that cannot be compile-time values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But per my understanding, for the first case, the argc value also can't be known during compile-time

You're confusing "parameters" with "arguments".

Parameters are the things in the function declaration that represent stuff the user passes in. Arguments are the actual stuff the user passes in at the site of a particular function call.

`argc` is an argument. The value of this may or may not be a constant expression, and if it is not, a `constexpr` function is fine.

`int` is used as the type for a parameter to `add`. `int` is a type which can be a constant expression. Now, not every `int` value is a constant expression, but it is a type that could theoretically be one.

Therefore, `add` can be a `constexpr` function, because its parameter list uses types which can be constant expressions. This is about the nature of the function itself.

The type `vector<T>` can *never* be a constant expression (in C++17, at any rate). As such, no `constexpr` function can take one as a parameter. Nor can it use one internally.

Answer (score 2):

The key requirement for a function to be a `constexpr` function:

> If its input is known at compile time, its results can be computed at compile time.

However, a `constexpr` is also a regular function. If its inputs are known only at run time, its results will be computed at run time.

Given your example, if you use:

```
 constexpr int a = add(5, 10);
```

the result of the function call can be evaluated at compile time since its inputs are known at compile time.

Use of

```
return add(argc, argc);
```

is a valid use of the function too. The inputs to the function in this call are known only at run time. Hence, the result function call can be evaluated only at run time.

Answer (score 0):

> So how to understand constexpr function has "everything it needs" to
>   compute its result at compile-time?

This line in the link refers to <sup>[1]</sup>:

```
constexpr int add(int a, int b)  
{
    return a + b;
}

static constexpr int val = add(3, 4); // [1] here
```

`add()` has two parameters which are literals.
The values are known at *compile time* which are `3` and `4`.

> But per my understanding, for the first case, the `argc` value also
>   can't be known during compile-time, and its value should be got at
>   running time, correct?

A variable or argument whose value can't be known during compile time can still be used as a parameter to a `constexpr` function. [As long as the parameter type is a literal type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#3.3).